# analysis question related to $L^p$ type inequalities 

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Dear mathoverflowers.

Just wondering if the following inequality is true.  For all $ p >1$ there is some $C$ such that

$ |  |x+1|^p-|y+1|^p -p(x-y)| \le C ( |x|+|y| + |x|^{p-1} + |y|^{p-1} ) |x-y| $ for all real numbers $ x$ and $y$.

thanks..

Comment: @Peter: So is the LHS along the diagonal.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it's true. Say we follow the line $(x,\alpha x)$ for $x > 0$ and $0 < \alpha < 1$. Both sides of the desired inequality have no linear part at $0$, so we examine the second derivatives. Keeping only dependence of the coefficients on $\alpha$, the second derivative of the LHS goes like
$$(1-\alpha)(1+x)^{p-2}$$
and for the RHS goes like
$$(1-\alpha)(1+x^{p-2}).$$
It is clear that the left is controlled by a constant independent of $\alpha$ times the right for all $x > 0$. The other regions can probably be taken care of similarly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I will attempt to follow through with the details.  

Answer (score 0):

If $p=2n$, a positive even integer, then your inequality is true -- use polar coordinates.
In view of this fact, I think your inequality should be true for all $p>1$.

Comment: I agree with you analysis.  thanks. 